# Expected number of directed links in a network

Tags: connectedness, random-graphs, network

Suppose we have a network with **n** nodes, in which every directed link exists with probability **p** (independent from each other). What would be the expected number of directed links if we express them in **n** and **p**? For example E(p,n) = ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L(n)$ be the number of all possible links on the network with $n$ nodes (this is either $n^2$ or $n^2 - n$ depending on whether you allow a node to be incident to itself or not). In the situation you describe you have $L(n)$ independent Bernoulli distributions each with parameter $p$ and are asking for the expected total number of successes, that is, you are actually looking at a binomial distribution with parameters $L(n)$ and $p$ and asking for the expected value of it, which is $p L(n)$.

Comment: thank you. Just one more thing based on your experience, can self-links be regarded as directed links?

Comment: Well,it will mostly depend on what kind of network you have in mind and whether a self-link makes sense there. For me the most natural way to model a directed link is as pair $(a,b)$ where the direction is from the node $a$ to the node $b$. From this structural point of view, it makes perfectly sense to talk about the directed self-link $(a,a)$ for the node $a$.